# Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan) error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, t-test

I have the following command below:

```
Townames = []
Notowns = [] 
def run_ttest():
    for key,value in enumerate(data['RegionName']):
                 if value in stateslist:
                    indexing = data['differ'].iloc[key]
                    Townames.append(indexing) 
                 else:
                    indexing = data['differ'].iloc[key]
                    Notowns.append(indexing)
    Unitowns = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Unitownvalues'])
    Notunitowns = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Notunitownvalues'])
    Unitowns['Unitownvalues'] = Townames      
    Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'] = Notowns 
    Unitowns = Unitowns.dropna(subset=['Unitownvalues'])
    Notunitowns = Notunitowns.dropna(subset=['Notunitownvalues'])
    return 
run_ttest()
from scipy import stats 
stats.ttest_ind(Unitowns['Unitownvalues'],Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'])
```

However, my output is:

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

I cannot understand why this is.

I **removed the NAN values above**: `Unitowns['Unitownvalues']` and `Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'].`

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add the final argument (the **assumption is that the variances of the two datasets** which you are comparing will be **equal**):

```
stats.ttest_ind(Unitowns['Unitownvalues'],Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'],equal_var=True)
```

rather than:

```
stats.ttest_ind(Unitowns['Unitownvalues'],Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'])
```

This then gave me an output of:

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=0.38697667088831, pvalue=0.69878181110717441)
```